# ffmpeg, unknown encoder xvid

Tags: ffmpeg

I installed ffmpeg with brew and got the 'Unknown encoder xvid' error when I tried to convert an mp4 to flv. Below is the command I used

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vcodec xvid -s 640x480 test.flv
```

If you need more information, please let me know. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-vcodec libxvid` instead, though this is only supported for encoding. You may wish to omit this altogether and let ffmpeg hash out the decoding codec automatically. I would feed ffmpeg...

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vcodec flv -s 640x480 test.flv
```

I believe all the parameters listed after your input file apply to the output file.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get this error "Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?)". How can I fix it?